# Module-level tests in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am getting acquainted to Haskell, currently writing my third "homework" to some course I found on the web. The homework assignment needs to be presented* in a file, named `Golf.hs`, starting with `module Golf where`. All well and good, this seems to be idiomatic in the language.

However, I am used to python modules ending in `if __name__ == "__main__:`, where one can put tests over the module, including during module development.`ghc` doesn't seem happy with such an approach:

```
$ ghc Golf.hs -o Golf && ./Golf

<no location info>: error:
    output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
```

Even though using `cabal` seems to be the norm, I would like to also understand the raw command-line invocations, that make programs work. `ghci` seems to be another approach to testing newly written code, yet reloading modules is peta. What is the easiest way to write some invocations of my functions with predefined test data and observe on `stdout` the result?

<sub>* - for students, who actually attend the course, I just follow the lecture notes and strive to complete the homeworks</sub>

Golf2.hs:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

module Golf2 where

foo :: Int -> Int
foo n = 42

main = putStr "Hello"
```

The output:

```
$ ghc Golf2.hs -o Golf2
[1 of 1] Compiling Golf             ( Golf2.hs, Golf2.o )

Golf2.hs:6:5: warning: [-Wunused-matches] Defined but not used: ‘n’

Golf2.hs:8:1: warning: [-Wmissing-signatures]
    Top-level binding with no type signature: main :: IO ()

<no location info>: error:
    output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
because there is no Main module.
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error. What's the minimal `Golf.hs` that reproduces that behaviour?

Comment: @Zeta I'm sure it's a silly question, and could probably resolve it by myself by rtfm, but there seem to pop too many of those questions at the moment.

Comment: As the error says, you should rename your module to `Main` or import it from another main module.

Comment: You can always reload a module using `:reload` in ghci.

Comment: @dimid the module and file are named as per the homework assignment. I was hoping to preserve the simple workflow "write functions -> write invocations with test data -> compile -> run -> observe stdout". `reload`-ing modules in `ghci` is extra steps. Writing a separate `Main.hs`, which imports `Golf.hs` is extra steps plus spatial fragmentation. Maybe `runghc`  could aid me. I have never used it.

Comment: @Vorac Yeah, in that case you can just run `runghc Golf.hs`, but IMHO ghci is easier.

Comment: " I would like to also understand the raw command-line invocations, that make programs work. " then just use `cabal` and run it with `-v3`, in which case it will print all of the commands it runs to build your program. Also, one should note that re-loading a module in GHCi will basically always be much, much faster than compiling (except, when your code consists of 10 lines or so).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ghci` is a really useful tool for learning!

When you only have one module, it's very easy, too. Start `ghci`, then `:l Golf.hs`. This will load your file. Then you'll be able to type `foo 342` and see "42" displayed, or `main` and see "hello". You can edit the file, then use `:reload` or `:r` to load your changes. [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/getting-started.html) has a good intro to using `ghci`.

This is a little easier than using `ghc` or tools like `cabal`, and all you really need while you're learning the very basics.

Comment: This seems to be a classical example of XY problem. I was asking how to structure modules for testability, and the best solutions turns out to be `ghci`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `ghc`-the-compiler (instead of its interactive variant `ghci`), you might use the [`-main-is`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html?highlight=main-is#ghc-flag--main-is) option.

From the docs:

> `-main-is⟨thing⟩`
>
> The normal rule in Haskell is that your program must supply a main function in module `Main`. When testing, it is often convenient to
>   change which function is the “main” one, and the `-main-is` flag allows
>   you to do so. The `⟨thing⟩` can be one of:
>
> - A lower-case identifier `foo`. GHC assumes that the main function is `Main.foo`.
> - A module name `A`. GHC assumes that the main function is `A.main`.
> - A qualified name `A.foo`. GHC assumes that the main function is `A.foo`.

So, try `ghc -main-is Golf2 Golf2.hs -o Golf2 && ./Golf2`.